# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::filter() in wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 805

Tags: taxonomy, fatal-error

Hi I just updated my WP site from 3.8.1 to 4.4.1 version ([related to this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215916/cant-update-database-after-wordpress-update-from-3-8-1-to-4-4-1)). After update I got this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::filter() in D:\wamp\www\mysite\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 805

We have our own plugin managed. To check if the issue is because of the plugin, I have switched to the default wp theme. But no luck there is still this error message. I know if the issue is with the plugin then it should be deactivated to debug, however I can't do that because all the features are from that plugin which is used in other sites as well and it's working fine even after updating WP to the latest version on those sites.

If I change:

```
$_term->filter( $filter );
```

To:

```
if(method_exists($_term, 'filter')) {
$_term->filter( $filter );
}
```

the error is not there but the page doesn't come up how it should be. Is there anyway I can fix this issue without editing the core wp file?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that you WP copy is customized? Not then use fresh version.

Comment: WP copy is not customized and have used the fresh copy for all except theme and all the plugins have been updated to the latest versions. The error is seen from WP version 4.4, it works fine upto version 4.3.2 though. Thanks

Comment: The method `WP_Term::filter()` was added in 4.4, it is really strange that you get a error saying that `WP_Term::filter()` doesn't exist when you upgrade to WP 4.4. Maybe you are using `get_term()` function some where before `WP_Term` class is loaded? Note that the error says "undefined method stdClass::filter()" and not "undefined method WP_Term::filter()"

Comment: It is quite impossible to tell exactly where the issue is. If everything works on one site with the same setup and not on the other, you can have a corrupt WordPress install, a hacked installation or an issue with a corrupt db

Comment: @cybmeta, thanks a lot for mentioning "undefined method stdClass::filter()". Its actually the issue of the object that we have created in our plugin. While merging the arrays in add filter hook, the object got altered where that should have been "WP_Term" object. This has been resolved by returning the same object i.e. $term and this works perfect. Thanks again greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help.